# Is searchkick or elastic search known to slow down response time?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

So we just recently added searchkick and elastic search to our web app but when we run locally it randomly slows the loading time and it slows it down a lot. On our heroku server it doesn't seem to slow it down much though. Did we do something wrong when using the gem. We are trying to add a search for users so here is the code that we changed when trying to add this feature and if someone could tell me if we did something wrong that would be great cause I don't know where else to turn to other than removing this nice gem off of our application.

```
  # GET /users
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @users = User.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
    else
      @users = User.all.page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

User javascript

```
$ ->
  $('#user_search').typeahead
    name: "user"
    remote: "/users/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
```

User model

```
searchkick autocomplete: ['username']
```

index page for the users

```
<%= form_tag users_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
        <% if params[:query].present? %>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <%= link_to "clear", users_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", id: "user_search", autocomplete: "off" %>
        <div class=input-group-btn">
            <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I have never seen this before in the logs before when all I am doing is just logging on. Can someone please explain why it's doing this now.

```
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '847873977044d6a6cd2f7f0aca148c652e37d397' ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "wallposts" WHERE "wallposts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_user_info.html.erb (4.0ms)
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."followed_id" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = ?  [["follower_id", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ?  [["followed_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (57.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_wallpost_form.html.erb (19.0ms)
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "wallposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 1) OR user_id = 1) AND (directed_user_id = user_id)
  Wallpost Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "wallposts".* FROM "wallposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 1) OR user_id = 1) AND (directed_user_id = user_id) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "wallposts" WHERE (user_id IN (SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
 WHERE follower_id = 1) OR user_id = 1) AND (directed_user_id = user_id)
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered shared/_feed_item.html.erb (40.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_feed.html.erb (55.0ms)
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Subscription Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0  [["user_id", 1]]
  Subforum Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subforums".* FROM "subforums" WHERE "subforums"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Topic Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."subforum_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["subforum_id", 1]]
  Subforum Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subforums".* FROM "subforums" WHERE "subforums"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Topic Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."subforum_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["subforum_id", 5]]
  Topic Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."subforum_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["subforum_id", 5]]
  Subforum Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subforums".* FROM "subforums" WHERE "subforums"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Topic Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."subforum_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["subforum_id", 2]]
  Subforum Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "subforums".* FROM "subforums" WHERE "subforums"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Topic Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."subforum_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["subforum_id", 6]]
  Topic Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."subforum_id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["subforum_id", 6]]
  Rendered shared/_subscription_feed.html.erb (93.0ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (256.0ms)
```

Comment: ElasticSearch is not known to slow things down, quite the opposite, it's usually very fast if the data you put in is properly structured, and I'm guessing you have it running in java, and that the gem is just how it's integrated in rails, and I have no idea how that works ?

Comment: ElasticSearch wont slow down response time at all, in fact its actually pretty fast!

Comment: Then why does it take 3-5 seconds or even longer to load pages at random times.

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific about what you're seeing in the logs that indicates there's a problem?  I don't see anything in there related to Elasticsearch at all.  Elasticsearch is a completely separate service running on your machine and the only way it would slow down a non-search related Rails request would be by slowing down your entire machine.